# How to register a DragEvent while already inside one and have it listen in the current DragEvent?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

My question is is related to the Drag and Drop API in Android. I apologize if my question was confusing. But essentially, when you want to start a Drag and Drop operation, you must invoke `startDrag()` on a `View`. You pass it in some info, and then you give it a `OnDragListener` in which to listen for a `View` which is being dragged. When the a drag is started, in my example a long press, all the Views that can accept any info are registered with the system to accept this info. It would make more sense if you quickly read through some of this in the android docs for [Drag and Drop](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html). But thats a quick overview of how it works assuming you havent used it before and would like to.

Now my question is essentially in an issue I have come across. I would like to create a `View` while the `onDragListener` is running that also accepts system info on a currently being dragged `View`. Problem is its not working. I am not surprised as the View was not registered when when the Drag operation first started. The question is how can I register it on the fly. The android docs shows you how to register it in the beginning but not when its already in one.

**MyDragListener** (Code for my onDragListener. Right now only playing with it.)

---

```
protected class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        // Defines a variable to store the action type for the incoming event
        final int action = event.getAction();

        // Handles each of the expected events
            switch(action) {

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    // Determines if this View can accept the dragged data
                    /*The way it works is it essentially turns anything that can accept stuff to Blue 
                     * or whatever color. It also does not need to do anything in terms of showing it can accept anything.*/
                    if(event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                        return (true);

                    } else {
                        return (false);
                    }
                //break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Height is: "+v.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                //break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    //this is triggered right after ACTIN_DRAG_ENTERED
                    Log.d("TestActivity", "Location of the View you are dragging is x: "+event.getX()+" y: "+event.getY());
                    if(v.getHeight()-10 < event.getY() && v.getHeight() > event.getY()&& showingView == false ) {

                            //here you are checking if its in the lower bound of the view
                            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext());
                            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_text, table, false);
                            ((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.da_text)).setText("Some text");
                            layout.setTag("Empty");
                            layout.startDrag(ClipData.newPlainText("Empty", "Empty"), new View.DragShadowBuilder(), null, 0);
                            table.addView(layout, Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())+1);
                        showingView = true;
                    }
                    return true;


                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    return true;
                //break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    //this is obvious, gets the data in the view that was dropped
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    return true;


            }//end of switch

        return false;
    }

}//end of MyDragListener
```

**Edit 1**

So I tried a different approach. I decided to have a holder for my `LinearLayout` which would be an item in the `TableLayout`. That way I would register the `OnDragListener` then I could just hold it until I needed it. That failed. The first time I used it, even if I added it to the TableLayout, it would not Listen to any drags, but when I dropped the drag and then long pressed it, it worked. So it has something to do with the fact that its invisible, and then its not. So by default it does not do anything when its invisible, and I am not sure how to make that not happen, and allow me to have it do something even when its invisible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post but if somebody needs a solution/hack...
I had struggled with this for a couple of hours and thought that it might be useful for someone.

**My problem**

I got this problem when I was trying to have my ListView scroll up/down while I was dragging an item. The issue was that when scrolling, the listview would load new converted views to the group view and the ones that were not active while the drag started (they were in the listview cache - and not associated as children for the view group) did not respond to the dragging.

You had the right idea about it, because the view missed the initial DRAG_STARTED event then it wasn't getting any other events.

I was going through the source code for VIEW/VIEW GROUP and there are a few ways that we can hack this thing. Eventually I decided to solve it by forcing a visibility change for the problematic view, which will start a chain of events that will eventually include the view in future DRAG EVENTS calls

**Solution: visibility change hack**

So after you have the new view attached to the parent simply set visibility to GONE and back to VISIBLE:

```
child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**Note:** do this while a) the user is still dragging b) the new view is already added to a parent.

**Note:** For me this was enough to solve the problem. BUT, in my case I had other views in the same container that were already accepting DRAG EVENTS. If this is the first child in that container it might not work. You can try to do the same trick to  the container ,and to the container's container, and so on until you reach a container that had children that accept the EVENTS.

Comment: Good solution. With mine I just ended up setting something similar. I just left a `View.GONE` TextView at the bottom that was registered with the `OnDragListener`. That way it always works because I always had an extra View to be used for that purpose. Either way. But it is pretty hacky with both our ways.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I was trying to do something very similar. A cleaner approach that worked for me was:

1. Attach the DragListener to the ExpandableListView instead of the individual views within it.
2. Then based on the x,y coordinated of DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION event, identify group or child view and do the required action.

This way the group/child view doesn't have to be visible at the time drag event started.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I think I found another interesting way to bring android to call the `View.OnDragListener onDrag()` of views that were added after the drag was initiated by `View.startDragAndDrop()`.

I ended up having a view with OnDragListener that saves the `DragEvent` (e.g. in a variable `dragStartEvent`) on the `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED`.
Now when I add a new view with an OnDragListener I call `dispatchDragEvent(dragStartEvent)` on the root layout of the current activity/fragment. I found the method in the android sources (with the comment `// TODO: Write real docs` on...), it dispatches the event to all descendant views. They then listen to all following events.