# Register OnDragListener after startDrag called

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am using Android Drag and Drop framework. I want to add another View dynamically to my layout after the startDrag method has been called. The problem is that the newly added View does not receive the drag callbacks. The only way I can think of is to add the view before the startDrag but make it transparent which seems like a hack. Is there a better way to dynamically add Views after the startDrag so that they receive the drag events of the ongoing drag?

Below is an example code snippet of what I am talking about:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
    View v = new View(context);
    v.setOnDragListener(myOnDragListener);
    container.addView(v);
    break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15097552/396106

Visibility hack of changing a view to vis/invis will trigger the new view to be used.

Answer (score 0):

call invalidate() on the view to redraw it

refer below:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
    View v = new View(context);
    v.setOnDragListener(myOnDragListener);
    container.addView(v);
    container.invalidate()
    break;
```