# How to make list elements get DragEvents after scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, drag-and-drop

**Short version:**

- Is there a way to make a newly created view receive `DragEvent`s of an already running drag-and-drop operation?

There's [How to register a DragEvent while already inside one and have it listen in the current DragEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697079/how-to-register-a-dragevent-while-already-inside-one-and-have-it-listen-in-the-c), but I'd really like a cleaner solution.

The suggested GONE->VISIBLE workaround is quite complex to get "right", because you need to make sure to only use it when a list item becomes visible and not unconditionally on all current list view items. In this the hack is slightly leaky without even more workaround code to get it right.

**Long version:**

I have a `ListView`. The elements of the `ListView` are custom View`s that contain dragable symbols (small boxes), e.g. similar to this:

[image: Example playout]

It is possible to drag the small boxes between the items of the `ListView`, like sorting elements into boxes. The drag handler on the list items is more or less trivial:

```
@Override
public boolean onDragEvent(DragEvent event)
{
    if ((event.getLocalState() instanceof DragableSymbolView)) {
        final DragableSymbolView draggedView = (DragableSymbolView) event.getLocalState();
        if (draggedView.getTag() instanceof SymbolData) {
            final SymbolData symbol = (SymbolData) draggedView.getTag();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                setSelected(true);
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                setSelected(false);
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                setSelected(false);
                // [...] remove symbol from soruce box and add to current box
                requestFocus();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return super.onDragEvent(event);
}
```

Dragging starts when holding the pointer over a symbol and starting to drag (i.e. moving it beyond a small threshold).

Now, however, the screen size may not be enough to contain all boxes and thus the `ListView` needs to scroll. I found out the hard way that I need to do implement the scrolling on my own since `ListView` does not automatically scroll while dragging.

In comes `ListViewScrollingDragListener`:

```
public class ListViewScrollingDragListener
    implements View.OnDragListener {

    private final ListView _listView;

    public static final int DEFAULT_SCROLL_BUFFER_DIP = 96;
    public static final int DEFAULT_SCROLL_DELTA_UP_DIP = 48;
    public static final int DEFAULT_SCROLL_DELTA_DOWN_DIP = 48;

    private int _scrollDeltaUp;
    private int _scrollDeltaDown;

    private boolean _doScroll = false;
    private boolean _scrollActive = false;

    private int _scrollDelta = 0;

    private int _scrollDelay = 250;
    private int _scrollInterval = 100;

    private int _scrollBuffer;

    private final Rect _visibleRect = new Rect();

    private final Runnable _scrollHandler = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if (_doScroll && (_scrollDelta != 0) && _listView.canScrollVertically(_scrollDelta)) {
                _scrollActive = true;
                _listView.smoothScrollBy(_scrollDelta, _scrollInterval);
                _listView.postDelayed(this, _scrollInterval);
            } else {
                _scrollActive = false;
            }
        }
    };

    public ListViewScrollingDragListener(final ListView listView, final boolean attach)
    {
        _scrollBuffer = UnitUtil.dipToPixels(listView, DEFAULT_SCROLL_BUFFER_DIP);
        _scrollDeltaUp = -UnitUtil.dipToPixels(listView, DEFAULT_SCROLL_DELTA_UP_DIP);
        _scrollDeltaDown = UnitUtil.dipToPixels(listView, DEFAULT_SCROLL_DELTA_DOWN_DIP);

        _listView = listView;
        if (attach) {
            _listView.setOnDragListener(this);
        }
    }

    public ListViewScrollingDragListener(final ListView listView)
    {
        this(listView, true);
    }

    protected void handleDragLocation(final float x, final float y)
    {
        _listView.getGlobalVisibleRect(_visibleRect);
        if (_visibleRect.contains((int) x, (int) y)) {
            if (y < _visibleRect.top + _scrollBuffer) {
                _scrollDelta = _scrollDeltaUp;
                _doScroll = true;
            } else if (y > _visibleRect.bottom - _scrollBuffer) {
                _scrollDelta = _scrollDeltaDown;
                _doScroll = true;
            } else {
                _doScroll = false;
                _scrollDelta = 0;
            }
            if ((_doScroll) && (!_scrollActive)) {
                _scrollActive = true;
                _listView.postDelayed(_scrollHandler, _scrollDelay);
            }
        }
    }

    public ListView getListView()
    {
        return _listView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
    {
        /* hide sequence controls during drag */
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            _doScroll = true;
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            _doScroll = false;
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            handleDragLocation(event.getX(), event.getY());
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This basically scrolls the `ListView` when you you drag near the upper or lower borders of its visible area. It's not perfect, but it's good enough.

However, there's a catch:

When the list scrolls to a previously invisible element, that element does not receive `DragEvent`s. It does not get selected (highlighted) when dragging a symbol over it nor does it accept drops.

Any ideas on how to make the "scrolled in" views receive `DragEvent`s from the already active drag-and-drop operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the fundamental problem is that `ViewGroup`(that `ListView` extends) caches a List of children to notify of `DragEvent`. Moreover, it only populates this cache when receiving **ACTION_DRAG_STARTED**. For more details peruse the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#1252).

On to the solution! Instead of listening for drop events on the individual rows of `ListView`, we're going to listen to them on `ListView` itself. Then, based on the coordinates of the events, we'll figure out which row the dragged view is being dragged from/to or hovered over. When the drop occurs, we'll perform the transaction of removing from the previous row and adding to the new row.

```
private void init(Context context) {
    setAdapter(new RandomIconAdapter()); // Adapter that contains our data set
    setOnDragListener(new ListDragListener());
    mListViewScrollingDragListener = new ListViewScrollingDragListener(this, false);
}

ListViewScrollingDragListener mListViewScrollingDragListener;

private class ListDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    // The view that our dragged view would be dropped on
    private View mCurrentDropZoneView = null;
    private int mDropStartRowIndex = -1;

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                // Update the active drop zone based on the position of the event
                updateCurrentDropZoneView(event);

                // Funnel drag events to separate listener to handle scrolling near edges
                mListViewScrollingDragListener.onDrag(v, event);

                if( mDropStartRowIndex == -1 )          // Only initialize once per drag->drop gesture
                {
                    mDropStartRowIndex = indexOfChild(mCurrentDropZoneView) + getFirstVisiblePosition();
                    log("mDropStartRowIndex %d", mDropStartRowIndex);
                }
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                mCurrentDropZoneView = null;
                mDropStartRowIndex = -1;
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // Update our data set based on the row that the dragged view was dropped in
                int finalDropRow = indexOfChild(mCurrentDropZoneView) + getFirstVisiblePosition();
                updateDataSetWithDrop(mDropStartRowIndex, finalDropRow);

                // Let adapter update ui
                ((BaseAdapter)getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

                break;
        }

        // The ListView handles ALL drag events all the time. Fine for now since we don't need to
        // drag -> drop outside of the ListView.
        return true;
    }

    private void updateDataSetWithDrop(int fromRow, int toRow) {
        log("updateDataSetWithDrop fromRow %d and toRow %d", fromRow, toRow);
        sIconsForListItems[fromRow]--;
        sIconsForListItems[toRow]++;
    }

    // NOTE: The DragEvent in local to DragDropListView, as are children coordinates
    private void updateCurrentDropZoneView(DragEvent event) {
        View previousDropZoneView = mCurrentDropZoneView;
        mCurrentDropZoneView = findFrontmostDroppableChildAt(event.getX(), event.getY());
        log("mCurrentDropZoneView updated to %d for x/y : %f/%f with action %d",
                mCurrentDropZoneView == null ? -1 : indexOfChild(mCurrentDropZoneView) + getFirstVisiblePosition(),
                event.getX(), event.getY(), event.getAction());

        if (mCurrentDropZoneView != previousDropZoneView) {
            if (previousDropZoneView != null) previousDropZoneView.setSelected(false);
            if (mCurrentDropZoneView != null) mCurrentDropZoneView.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The next four methods are utility methods taken from Android Source Code. Most are package-private on View
 * or ViewGroup so I'm forced to replicate them here. Original source can be found:
 * http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#ViewGroup.findFrontmostDroppableChildAt%28float%2Cfloat%2Candroid.graphics.PointF%29
 */
private View findFrontmostDroppableChildAt(float x, float y) {
    int childCount = this.getChildCount();
    for(int i=0; i<childCount; i++)
    {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (isTransformedTouchPointInView(x, y, child)) {
            return child;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

static public boolean isTransformedTouchPointInView(float x, float y, View child) {
    PointF point = new PointF(x, y);
    transformPointToViewLocal(point, child);
    return pointInView(child, point.x, point.y);
}

static public void transformPointToViewLocal(PointF pointToModify, View child) {
    pointToModify.x -= child.getLeft();
    pointToModify.y -= child.getTop();
}

static public boolean pointInView(View v, float localX, float localY) {
    return localX >= 0 && localX < (v.getRight() - v.getLeft())
                && localY >= 0 && localY < (v.getBottom() - v.getTop());
}

static final int[] sIconsForListItems;
static final int NUM_LIST_ITEMS = 50;
static final int MAX_NUM_ICON_PER_ELEMENT = 8;
static {
    sIconsForListItems = new int[NUM_LIST_ITEMS];
    for (int i=0; i < NUM_LIST_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        sIconsForListItems[i] = (getRand(MAX_NUM_ICON_PER_ELEMENT));
    }
}

private static final String TAG = DragDropListView.class.getSimpleName();
private static void log(String format, Object... args) {
    Log.d(TAG, String.format(format, args));
}
```

Lots of comments so hopefully the code is self-documenting. A few notes:

- RandomIconAdapter is just a basic adapter extending BaseAdapter and backed by sIconsForListItems.
- ListViewScrollingDragListener is the same as the one in the prompt.
- Tested on GS6 5.0.2